# ASP.NET MVC: Return different views depending on object type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, polymorphism

In my controller, I'm generically deserializing Xml. The object being deserialized to could end up being any number of different types. This, of course, won't be known at compile time. I've created a number of partial views, each of which are strongly typed to a different object that is a possible outcome of the Xml deserializaton.

My problem is that I'm struggling with a good way to return the right view. I could always switch on some property in the object, or use a Key/ViewName Dictionary mapping to get the right view name, but I was hoping for something a little more generic than that.

Does anyone know of a way that I could implicitly say, "return the view that is typed off of the object I have."?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code it's hard to tell if what you're doing fits in with any best practice however from the outside, it does seem like your approach might be somewhat confusing and restrictive.

That said, you could simply name your views using the type name.

something like `return View(xmlObject.GetType().Name + "View");`

Comment: I can provide more context. I've multiple child types that all inherit from a base type. I'm using System.Xml.Serialization attributes on my base and sub-classes to direct the serializer how to structure the Xml. On the base class, I use [XmlInclude] to indicate any of the sub-types can be serialized by using a serializer typed off the base class. This provides the genericism, so that when the Xml is later deserialized back into an object,it can be stored into a base object, but maintain a type of the sub-class. So I can end up with objects of different types, depending on what was serialized.